# Using Hibernate Sessions features along with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know that Spring Data JPA uses Hibernate, however, I have some questions that need clarification.

- Will I be able to use other Hibernate features such as C3P0, Hibernate second level caching, or Hibernate sessions if I use Spring Data JPA?
- What are the advantages of using @Query for writing custom queries over using hibernate sessions and HQL?
- Is there any performance difference between using Spring Data JpaRepository query methods and using Hibernate HQL?

I have seen the other similar questions here and they don't answer these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that Spring Data JPA uses Hibernate

No. It uses JPA. Even though Hibernate is the default JPA implementation of Spring Boot, and the most popular JPA implementation, any JPA engine can be used.

> Will I be able to use other Hibernate features such as C3P0

C3P0 has nothing to do with Hibernate. It's a connection pool. You can use any connection pool you wnt both with Spring and with Hibernate. Spring Boot uses HikariCP by default, and I would stick to that (it's a very good pool).

> Hibernate second level caching

Yes.

> or Hibernate sessions if I use Spring Data JPA?

There's really no good reason to use the old, proprietary Hibernate Session API, instead of using the standard JPA API. If you really need to, I don't see why you couldn't use it, but I wouldn't (and never had to).

> What are the advantages of using @Query for writing custom queries over using hibernate sessions and HQL?

Query takes a HQL (JPQL, to be exact) query. If you use Query, you use HQL. The advantage is that you just need to declare the query. the binding of parameters, execution of the query, paging, etc. are done for you by Spring. But you can use custom repository implementations and use the native JPA API if you need to.

> Is there any performance difference between using Spring Data JpaRepository query methods and using Hibernate HQL?

No.